# Implication of redundant code warning

Tags: c#, .net

When Visual Studio greys out some code and tells you it is redundant, does this mean the compiler will ignore this code or will it still compile this code? In other words, would this redundant code never be interpreted or will it be? Or does it simply act as a reminder that the code is simply not required?

If I leave redundant code in my classes/structs etc, will it have an impact on performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the code is redundant it's not necessary for compilation, but leaving it in won't have any impact on performance.

As the compiler has identified the code as redundant in Visual Studio it won't get compiled into the IL or machine code.

It's not good practice to leave redundant code in your project. If you need the code in the future you should get it from the older versions of the file in your source code repository.

Answer (score 0):

C# is not an interpreted language, it's a JITted (Just-In-Time compiled) language, which means it's compiled from MSIL at runtime.  Thus, the JITter can do analysis to determine whether code is redundant, and then remove it.

There will be two opportunities to remove redundant code

1. Compiling C# to MSIL in Visual Studio.
2. JITting MSIL to assembly at run (or install) time.

Because the C# compiler itself has flagged this issue, that means the code will likely be removed during (1).

So yeah, it's just being nice and reminding you.  Most compilers remove redundant code in many different and subtle ways without telling the programmer, but in certain obvious cases it's a good idea to tell the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not compiled.

Can drive me nuts sometimes when testing and I want to use the debuggers "set next statement" command to some statement and it wasn't compiled.